# Как добавить свою иконку MaterialUi?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Как добавить свою иконку MaterialUi?
Пробовал следующим образом:

```
// webpack.config.js
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
}

// ---
import StarIcon from './star.svg';

<SvgIcon component={StarIcon} inheritViewBox />
```

Но ничего не получилось.

Comment: Попробуйте `import { ReactComponent as StarIcon } from './star.svg';`

Comment: Получилось, огромное спасибо!!!